# How can I append a calculated value to the end of a bar in Chart.JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm generating a horizontal bar graph that looks like this:

[image]

I need it to look something like this:

[image]

That is to say, I need the percentage difference between week 1 (the top/green bar) and week 2 (the bottom/orange bar) to be appended to the week 2 bars.

I'm adding the vals to the bars themselves with this code:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function (chartInstance) {
        var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
        // render the value of the chart above the bar
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(14, 'bold', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                ctx.fillText(addCommas(dataset.data[i]), model.base + 20, model.y + 6);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

...but don't know how to make a calculation and append that to the end of the bars.

For the full "monty" here's the rest of the jQuery for this chart:

```
var ctxForecastChart = $("#forecastLineChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var forecastChartData = {
    labels: [
        "Total Qty", "Total Sales"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "9/18/2016",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(34,139,34,0.75)",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(34,139,34,1)",
            data: [100, 1000.00]
        },
        {
            label: "9/25/2016",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,51,0.75)",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,51,1)",
            data: [110, 1110.11]
        }
    ]
};

var optionsForecast = {
    tooltips: {
        enabled: true
    }
};

var forecastBarChart = new Chart(ctxForecastChart,
{
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: forecastChartData,
    options: optionsForecast
});
```

### UPDATE

Tektiv's code looks very promising, but for some reason it completely breaks my charts. With my code:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function (chartInstance) {
        var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
        // render the value of the chart above the bar
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(14, 'bold', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                ctx.fillText(addCommas(dataset.data[i]), model.base + 20, model.y + 6);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

...I see this:

[image]

With the new code replacing that above:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function (chartInstance) {
        var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(14, 'bold', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);

        // `start` makes a better rendering IMO
        ctx.textAlign = 'start';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#666';

        chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.base + 5, model.y + 6);

                if (i == 1) {
                    // `Total Sales` values here

                    // If needed, here you get the other dataset
                    var otherDataset = chartInstance.data.datasets[(dataset._meta[0].controller.index == 1) ? 0 : 1];

                    // Get the value you want to display
                    var value = Math.round((Math.abs(dataset.data[i] - otherDataset.data[i]) / dataset.data[i]) * 100);

                    // Display it with the `x` property of the model
                    ctx.fillText(value + "%", model.x + 5, model.y + 6);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

...I see this:

[image]

I have no idea why - the new code looks fine, AFAICT.

### UPDATE 2

The updated code is a little better, but it still torques the other charts:

[image]

### UPDATE 3

Apparently it's a problem of dueling OnDraw() events; I also have this one aimed at the Price Compliance chart:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function (chartInstance) {
        var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
        // render the value of the chart above the bar
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(14, 'bold', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                ctx.fillText(addCommas(dataset.data[i]), model.base + 20, model.y + 6);
                //ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.base + 20, model.y + 6);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you get these `10%` & `11.1%` values ? I didn't get this part

Comment: With Paint; that's the example of how I want the chart to look; that's my question: how do I make it look like that?

Comment: Small misunderstanding here. I meant how do you **calculate** these values ? I didn't get the part you are talking about the difference. Are you doing (`orange / green`, `green / orange` ...) ?

Comment: The first set of values are of one color, and the other are the other color, as specified in the datasets part of forecastChartData. I do not yet have a way of programmatically calculating the value - that's another problem. For now I'm using Calculator (difference divided by original number * 100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you did with `model.base` when you are adding the data, do the following :

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function(chartInstance) {
        var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(14, 'bold', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);

        // `start` makes a better rendering IMO
        ctx.textAlign = 'start';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#666';

        chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.base + 5, model.y + 6);

                if (dataset._meta[0].controller.index == 1) {
                    // Orange bar (2nd dataset) values here

                    // We get the other dataset
                    var otherDataset = chartInstance.data.datasets[(dataset._meta[0].controller.index == 1) ? 0 : 1];

                    // Then calculate the percentage difference
                    var value = Math.round((Math.abs(dataset.data[i] - otherDataset.data[i]) / otherDataset.data[i]) * 100);

                    // And finally we display it
                    ctx.fillText(value + "%", model.x + 5, model.y + 6);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

---

You can see the plugin working [in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8zmupu6/), and here is how it looks like :

[image]

Comment: I just realized my requirements are wrong; the "10%" should actually be appended to the "110" bar (week 2 being a 10% improvement in qty), and the 11% should be appended to week 2 Sales. I will replace the "this is how I want it to look" image.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I edited everything (code, fiddle ..) to fit your new request. Is it alright ?

Comment: Looks awesome; I will czech it out. Please see my update to the problem I was having (I'll see if the new code changes that). A little better, but still breaks the other charts; see Update 2.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon The problem comes from the fact that plugins affect **all** the charts on your page. If you could make a piece of code (using [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) for instance) containing your 4 charts, that would be great since I could take a look at what's not working.

Comment: There's no way to limit the code to a single chart? I need separate functionality for another chart. I'll show it in Update 3.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon You can use `chartInstance.id` property. Use it to check on which chart the code is affecting. Take a look [at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8zmupu6/1/) : only the first chart is affected since I added `if (chartInstance.id != 0) return;` at the beginning of the plugin (*remember it is 0-based indexed*).

Comment: That's a great tip - using "if (chartInstance.id != N) return;" is what I needed.